# Simple Update Join much slower than it should be (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, join, update

This is a simple Update Join that updates only about 100 rows:

```
Update A INNER JOIN B using(id) SET A.active = 1 WHERE A.date > '2020'
```

This takes about 30 seconds to run, despite the fact that:

- This query updates the same 100 rows and takes milliseconds to run:

  `Update A SET active = 1 WHERE date > '2020'`
- The join condition is fast, this query does the same join and takes less than a second

  `SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B using(id) WHERE A.date > '2020'`
- The field `active` not part of any index
- Table A has an index on (id, date), and table B has an index on id.

I tried putting the where condition in the join (using on date > '2020') but it didn't help. I'm absolutely stumped why this takes so long. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Table B is used for rows restriction only. Rewrite JOIN to WHERE EXISTS. *This takes about 30 seconds to run* How many rows there is in table B?  *This query updates the same 100 rows* If so does the table B usage is needed really? *`using(id)`* In common `id` is primary key. Does it is not in your tables?

Comment: What is `B` for?  To limit which items are to be set `active`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.active = 1
    WHERE A.date >= '2020-01-01'
      AND ( EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.id = A.id ) )
```

What is the datatype of `date`?  If it is `DATE`, you were excluding New Year's Day.

I'm assuming that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` if each table.  But, given that, I must ask why you have two tables with the same PK -- That is usually poor schema design.  (There are exceptions.)  Furthermore, `INDEX(id, date)` is probably useless.

Needed:  A:  `INDEX(date)`.  Even so, that might be ignored, depending on the data distribution.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...`